# Source a file in gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle.properties

Is there a way in gradle to 'source' a file in gradle? The project has a file (project.properties) that has about one hundred properties being exported, like

```
export PROP1=value1
export PROP2=value2.....
export PROP100=value100
```

These properties are used in multiple tasks inside gradle. Question is how can I just source this file (project.properties) inside my build script?, that should have the same effect of executing the command **source project.properties** in a command prompt.

Doing something like below gives error -  Cannot run program "source": error=2, No such file or directory

```
task sampleTask () {
  'source project.properties'.execute()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its possible as mentioned here https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-execute-shell-command-source-or-dot-doesnt-work-with-exec/7271/7 . P.S. the sourced properties ain't gonna be availble to other processes run by other gradle tasks. Correct me if I'm wrong.